# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to compile fragment shader Error in Tensorflow.js project

Tags: javascript, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm using [face-api.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js) Javascript API to develop a web app that user uploads her/his picture and we want to detect faces in the picture.

On the other hand I used VGGface 16 model json formatted to predict that user uploaded image is similar to which celebrity.

following are my javascript codes:

```
const MODEL_URL = '../faceapi_models'
Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
    // faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri(MODEL_URL),
])
.then((val) => {
    console.log('val')
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

let model
async function loadModel() {
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel('../web_model/vgg_model.json');
}
loadModel()
.then((val) => {
    console.log('Model is Loaded');
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('Model Not Load : ' + err)
})

let croppedImage = null;
const user_pic = document.getElementById('user_pic')
const preview = document.getElementById('preview')
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

window.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = preview.width;
    canvas.height = preview.height;
    ctx.drawImage(preview, 0, 0);
};

preview.onclick = () => user_pic.click()
    
user_pic.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        };
        img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(user_pic.files[0]);

    detectFaces(user_pic.files[0])
})


async function detectFaces(input) {
    let imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(input)
    const imgElement = new Image()
    imgElement.src = imgURL

    const results = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(imgElement)
        .then(results => {

            if (Array.isArray(results) && results.forEach) {
                results.forEach(result => {

                    const { x, y, width, height } = result.box;

                    const crop = ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
                    croppedImage = new ImageData(crop.data, width, height);

                    const input = tf.browser.fromPixels(croppedImage);    

                    const resizedImage = tf.image.resizeBilinear(input, [224, 224]);
                    const inputTensor = resizedImage.expandDims(0);

                    const predictions =  model.predict(inputTensor).data();

                    const celebrityIndex = predictions.indexOf(Math.max(...predictions));
                    
                    console.log(celebrityIndex)

                    // const celebrityName = celebrityLabels[celebrityIndex];

                    // Display the results
                    // const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result');
                    // resultDisplay.innerHTML = `Most similar celebrity: ${celebrityName}`;

                });
            } else {
                console.error('Results is not an array or does not have a forEach function.');
            }
        });
}
```

I have solve many problem that I have yet but I do not know how to handle this problem and Why did this problem arise?

This is complete erorr :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that problem is with `x, y, width, height` constants that had float values. a simple way is converting those to Int like this :

```
const {x, y, width, height} = result.box;
const xInt = Math.floor(x);
const yInt = Math.floor(y);
const widthInt = Math.floor(width);
const heightInt = Math.floor(height);
```